# My multilabel classification RNN is not learning

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I have made a model that tries to predict the chances of every piano key playing in a time step given all time steps before it. I tried making a GRU network with 88 outputs(one for every piano key)

input shape = (600,88,)

desired output/ label shape = (88, )

```
import numpy as np
import midi_processer
from keras import models
from keras import layers

x_train, x_test = np.load("samples.npy", mmap_mode='r'), np.load("test_samples.npy", mmap_mode='r')

y_train, y_test = np.load("labels.npy", mmap_mode='r'), np.load("test_labels.npy", mmap_mode='r')

def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input(shape=(600,88,)))
    model.add(layers.GRU(512,activation='tanh',recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
    model.add(layers.RepeatVector(600))
    model.add(layers.GRU(512,activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(88, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    return model

x_partial, x_val = x_train[:13000], x_train[13000:]
y_partial, y_val = y_train[:13000], y_train[13000:]

model = build_model()
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_partial, y_partial, batch_size = 50, epochs = , validation_data= (x_val,y_val))
```

instead of learning normally my algorithm had stayed with constant accuracy throughout all of the epochs

```
Epoch 1/15
260/260 [==============================] - 998s 4s/step - loss: -0.1851 - accuracy: 0.0298 - val_loss: -8.8735 - val_accuracy: 0.0310
Epoch 2/15
260/260 [==============================] - 827s 3s/step - loss: -33.6520 - accuracy: 0.0382 - val_loss: -56.0122 - val_accuracy: 0.0310
Epoch 3/15
260/260 [==============================] - 844s 3s/step - loss: -78.6130 - accuracy: 0.0382 - val_loss: -98.2798 - val_accuracy: 0.0310
Epoch 4/15
260/260 [==============================] - 906s 3s/step - loss: -121.0963 - accuracy: 0.0382 - val_loss: -139.3440 - val_accuracy: 0.0310
Epoch 5/15
```

Comment: Are your labels binary encoded?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I believe they are, I added the shape of the input and labels to the question

Comment: Instead of adding the shapes, provide samples from those arrays. To me, it seems there are negative values.

Comment: @Frightera to pad otu the space in the music samples I added negative values where the music piece is over, is that not okay? if not is there any alternative?

Comment: Binary labels literally means 0 or 1, no other value, and that is what the binary cross-entropy loss expects. Getting a negative loss usually means you did not have binary labels.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy first of all thank you very much for answering, second of all is there any alternative to padding with -1? or is there maybe a different loss that also includes negative values?

Comment: I don't see why you need padding to be honest here.

Comment: I recommend you use other metrics for your model. Like precision and recall.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I need all of my inputs to be the same size vector no?

Comment: Yes but it also depends if there is a label for the whole sequence, or multiple labels per sequence, and also for padding values it should report no prediction (the negative class).